# Does the processor, disk and internal bus on my computer operate fast enough to send data from a disk file at 10 gigabits per second?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, cpu, pci

I would like to know if the processor, disk and internal bus on my computer operate fast enough to send data from a disk file at 10 gigabits per second?

```
% cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x21
cpu MHz     : 1286.233
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 4988.39
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual



% sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda         
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-6-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075
Serial Number:    33BWT0STT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 4a1f83658
Firmware Version: AX0R2J
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jan 26 23:16:14 2020 WET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled



% lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
           +-01.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M]
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
           +-1a.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
           +-1b.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
           +-1c.0-[02]--
           +-1c.1-[03]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
           +-1c.3-[04]--+-00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader
           |            \-00.2  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1d.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
```

Comment: well... since you hard disk is SATA 3.0 6Gb/s i would say, no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU has a theoretical peak capacity of 5GT/s to its memory controller, and up to 25.6GBps to memory, so it should be able to generate 10Gbps of traffic.

However, your laptop won’t have a 10Gbps NIC, and your hard drive uses a connection capped at 6Gbps (and is undoubtedly far slower than that, since it’s a disk spinning at 5400rpm). So you can’t read 10Gbps’ worth of traffic and you can’t send it to the network.

Take a look at [MoonGen](https://github.com/emmericp/MoonGen/) if you want to investigate traffic generation. [This paper on link flooding with commodity hardware](https://portail.telecom-bretagne.eu/publi/public/fic_download.jsp?id=63042) is also worth reading.

Comment: An NVMe SSD would break through that 6GBS SATA cap. But there remains the issue of the network connection speed.

Comment: @kmarsh The network connection speed in this question is a non-issue since it was explicitly not mentioned.

Comment: Suck it and see? Theory and practice are different worlds. Send 12Gbit of nulls to the disk with dd and time it. Send it from disk to /dev/null with dd and time it. dd is about as fast as you can get (specify bs= your file system block size unless you know your app will do better). Did you really mean  Gbit units?

Comment: I think there is a strong implication that "sending" at the common NIC speed of 10Gb/S means "network"